# Using SQL function with datatable results

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a database table with a DATETIME column. What I want to do is to identify whether the date part of a record is the same of with the date part of today. However, I have a datatable object and I cannot use daUsage.Select with the SQL function DATEPART.

So what I'm asking is whether there is a way to filter results from a datatable without using the select function. If this is possible how is it done? I could use LINQ but I'm pretty new to it and I feel that there must be a better way to do that.

Thanks

Comment: show some code, it's a lot easier to understand than reading all this text!

Comment: How are you populating the datatable? At some point this must be coming from a `SELECT` query, where you could apply a filter or add an additional column *before* the datatable ever see it. If you are just pointing at a table, maybe you could point at a view instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [DataTable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx) to check if your date is between 0 o'clock this day 0 o'clock next day:

```
string selectString = String.Format("DateColumn >= '{0}' AND DateColumn < '{1}'",
                      DateTime.Today.ToString(DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo), 
                      DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).ToString(DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo));
bool hasTodayRecords = dt.Select(selectString).Length > 0;
```

On this way you get only records of today.

In LINQ you could compare [DateTime.Date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) with `DateTime.Today`:

```
bool hasTodayRecords = dt.AsEnumerable().
     Any(r => DateTime.Today.Equals(((DateTime)r["DateColumn"]).Date));
```

Comment: Thank you for your help... it seems to be what I'm looking for. Shouldn't it be DateColumn < '{1}' since I don't want to include the next day?

Comment: @Andreas: I have edited it. But with `<=` you would only include records with exact 0'clock of the next day.